# Increase font size of the "Find" feature of Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, display-settings, accessibility

I'm getting older but I still have a keen interest in Asian languages.

With my eyesight not as good as it used to be I've increased the default font size in Windows which affects just about all of the UI across the OS and most apps. Obviously I can control+/control- to adjust the text size in a webpage in Chrome, or pinch-zoom.

But one annoying thing is that the text when I try to use "Find..." is just too tiny to read when I'm using Thai:
[image: Tiny Thai font in Chrome "Find"]

I've looked at Chrome's settings and their [Advanced Font Settings add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-font-settings/caclkomlalccbpcdllchkeecicepbmbm), but nothing affects the size of the text in the find input.

Would there be some way to adjust this?

Comment: What version of windows are you using? Windows 10's scaling functions can affect the size of the search box/text (along with everything else). But that's not an option for older windows.

Would the magnifier tool `Win`+`+` be a usable work-around? (`Win`+`Esc` to close)

Comment: I'm on Windows10. I can scale it up more but the fonts in everything else become too bulky when the Thai font gets just big enough to be clear. And unlike changing the font size in a browser, changing the system font size takes several seconds and hides everything while it's making the changes. So you can't zoom in and out with it. Thanks for the hotkeys though. I didn't know about those though I did know about the tool. It's better than nothing but it just makes the pixels bigger which isn't always enough to reveal the detail. I suppose that means it would be hard to read even with good eyes.

Comment: You can try running the ClearType adjustment to see if it can smooth out the fonts.